# Under what circumstances will Android kill an application if there is an exception on a child thread

Tags: android, multithreading

In a normal JVM process, an un-handled exception on a child thread will not cause the main thread to terminate. For example, the following Java code:

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread t  =  new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("BANG!");
        }
    });
    t.start();
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
}
```

will print something like:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Exception in thread "Thread-0" Hello World
java.lang.RuntimeException: BANG!
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:11)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

etc.

However, within an Android application the OS seems to terminate an application when an un-handled exception is thrown on a child thread. For example, in the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException("BANG!");
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
}
```

The OS will show a dialog informing the user that the application has stopped and the application will be closed.

However I have observed that this does not always happen. Sometimes the dialog is shown but the app is not shut down. Does anyone know under what circumstances un-handled exceptions in child threads will cause the app to  be killed.